# Removing \n from dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

How to remove the \n from the output ?

```
weather_list = []
for website in web:
  date = website.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div').text
  temp = website.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul').text
  weather_item = {'Dates':date,
                  'Temperature':temp}
  weather_list.append(weather_item)
df = pd.DataFrame(weather_list)
print(df)
```

The output has \n in dataframe how to get rid of that
**OUTPUT:**

```
      Dates    Temperature
0  Mon\n18.Oct  min.\n23°C
1  Mon\n18.Oct  min.\n23°C
2  Mon\n18.Oct  min.\n23°C
3  Mon\n18.Oct  min.\n23°C
4  Mon\n18.Oct  min.\n23°C
```

Comment: `df=df.replace('\n', '', regex=True)`?

Answer (score -1):

You could try this string replacement method for the temperature specific column.

```
df['Temperature'] = df['Temperature'].str.replace('\n', '')
```